# Persisting Redux state to local storage

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I've created a simple to do app using React. I've attempted to persist state using local storage. However, the local storage code I've added is somehow preventing my components from rendering altogether. Not only are the todos saved in state not appearing, none of my components will render. I get a blank page on refresh. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Here's what happens on the initial save after the local storage code is included. It loads the components just fine, but the to dos that are already in state are not shown:

[image]

After using the form to add to dos and refreshing the page, this happens. None of the components are shown whatsoever. Just a blank page.

[image]

Here is the local storage code inside my `index.js` file. I'm pretty sure the problem is here but I have included the code for the other components and the reducer as well:

```
const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('state') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) : [];

const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState);

store.subscribe(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
})
```

The `index.js` file in its entirety:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { reducer } from "./reducers/todoReducer";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('state') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) : [];

const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState);

store.subscribe(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

the other components:
`TodoList.js`:

```
import Todo from "./Todo";

const TodoList = props => {

    return (
        <ul className="task-list">
            {props.state.map(task => (
                <Todo task={task} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        state: state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList);
```

`TodoForm.js`:

```
const TodoForm = props => {
    const [newItemText, setNewItemText] = useState("");

    const handleChanges = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setNewItemText(e.target.value);
      };

    const saveState = () => localStorage.setItem("props.state", JSON.stringify(props.state));

    useEffect(() => {
        const todos = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if (todos) props.setState({ [props.state]: JSON.parse(props.state) })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="form-div">
                <input
                    className="add-input"
                    name="todo"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="enter a task"
                    value={newItemText}
                    onChange={handleChanges}
                />
                <button 
                    className="add-button"
                    onClick = {e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    props.addItem(newItemText);
                    saveState();
                    }}>Add a Task
                </button>
                <button 
                    className="add-button"
                    onClick={e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    props.removeCompleted();
                    }}>Remove Completed
                </button>
        </div>

    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        state: state
    } 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addItem, removeCompleted})(TodoForm);
```

`Todo.js`:

```
const Todo = props => {

    return (
            <li 
                className="tasks"
                style={{textDecoration: props.task.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}} 
                onClick={() => props.toggleCompleted(props.task.id)}>
                    {props.task.item}
            </li>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        state: state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {toggleCompleted})(Todo);
```

`todoReducer.js`:

```
export const initialState = [
    { item: 'Learn about reducers', completed: false, id: 1 },
    { item: 'review material from last week', completed: false, id: 2 },
    { item: 'complete reducer todo project', completed: false, id: 3 }
]

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_ITEM:
            // console.log(action.payload)
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    item: action.payload,
                    completed: false,
                    id: Date.now()
                }
            ]
        case TOGGLE_COMPLETED:
            const toggledState = [...state];
            toggledState.map(item => {
                if(item.id === action.payload) {
                    item.completed = !item.completed;
                }
            })
            console.log(toggledState);
            state = toggledState;
            return state;

        case REMOVE_COMPLETED:
           return state.filter(item => !item.completed);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

`App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

// components
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import TodoForm from "./components/TodoForm";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1 className="title">To Do List</h1>
        <TodoList />
        <TodoForm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`actions.js`:

```
export const ADD_ITEM = 'ADD_ITEM';
export const TOGGLE_COMPLETED = 'TOGGLE_COMPLETED';
export const REMOVE_COMPLETED = 'REMOVE_COMPLETED';

export const addItem = input => {
    return { 
        type: ADD_ITEM, payload: input
    }
  };

export const toggleCompleted = (id) => {
    return { 
        type: TOGGLE_COMPLETED, payload: id 
    }
  };

export const removeCompleted = () => {
    return { 
        type: REMOVE_COMPLETED 
    }
  };
```

Comment: The `localStore` part looks okay, I guess the issue is somewhere else. Did you check the `console` if there is any error message or warning appeared? Could you please add how you call the actions and additionally the `App.js` as well? Thanks!

Comment: Hummm I'm not seeing any error messages. I significantly edited the post to add the code you requested. I also added two screenshots to show what happens: Upon initial load, all my components render fine but the app is not picking up the data stored in state. Upon refresh, all of the components go away. Nothing is shown. Could this possibly be a middleware issue?

Comment: If you open the console and type there `localStorage.getItem('state')`, what do you see there? Might be a caching issue. Maybe an old value got stuck there.

Comment: It's logging the task that I've added via the form: "[{"item":"go to the store","completed":false,"id":1577966268922}]"